# Odd map_meta_cap $args on post edit -- sometimes integer, sometimes string

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I've been digging into the map_meta_cap filter since I need to extend the user's capabilities based on context, in certain situations.  This is working well but in my traces I noticed something odd about the way $args show up at the callback function.  Here's my filter registration (inside a class):

```
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', array(&$this, 'post_map_meta_cap'), 10, 4 );
```

and here's the callback function definition that goes with it:

```
public function post_map_meta_cap( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
    error_log("Filter fired:  ------>  meta_cap args:  " . json_encode($args));
}
```

Now, I'm on the admin page that shows all of my custom post types listed, and about to click on "edit" for one of the posts (id number 6).  Here's the trace:

```
on page: edit.php?post_type=my_custom_post_type
click on edit post id 6
Filter fired:  map_meta_cap:  ------>  meta_cap args:  [6]
Filter fired:  admin_enqueue_scripts
Filter fired:  admin_head
Filter fired:  in_admin_header
Filter fired:  admin_bar_menu
Filter fired:  wp_before_admin_bar_render
Filter fired:  wp_after_admin_bar_render
Filter fired:  map_meta_cap:  ------>  meta_cap args:  ["6"]
Filter fired:  in_admin_footer
Filter fired:  admin_footer_text
Filter fired:  admin_footer
Filter fired:  admin_print_footer_scripts
on page:  post.php?post=6&action=edit
```

I'm writing the value of $args with this:

```
json_encode($args)
```

which is a quick/easy way to get any object to be readable in a trace/log.

So, what I found odd is that as you can see the first time the filter is fired the $args array has one element which is an **integer**, 6.  The second time it fires the array has one element and is a **string**, "6".

I'm casting the result to integer just to be safe, now that I see this -- but I was wondering why it does this?  Do we expect the post id to sometimes be an integer and sometimes be a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map_meta_cap` function handles context arguments generically - you can give it anything and it'll happily pass it down the chain. It's only particular capabilities like `edit_post` that *expect* the argument to be an integer, but even then it's up to the caller to pass an appropriate value.

Here's where you get your string/integer mashups - usually the caller will pass the ID straight from a `WP_Post` object, but it could be from anywhere - another database call, another object that has a reference to a post ID, hardcoded etc. In other words, lots of opportunities for a string to slip through.

You can try a `debug_backtrace` on your tests to find the culprits, but there are more important things in life to get on with - stick to your int type-casting and carry on coding ;)

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  This particular filter is not really well documented so I wasn't sure what was going on.